# Camry 2004 , Engine Cranking but not starting!

Tags: engine, toyota, starting, camry

I have Camry 2004 it's not starting but the engine is cranking. The technician told me that the problem is from the computer of the car. Is this true? By the way, I faced the same issue 2 years ago and I replaced the computer! But again it stopped.
What shall I do ?

For your information;

Mileage : 254,140.8176 mile.

1. The fuel is there and the fuel pump is OK.
2. There is no spark!
3. Fuses and wires are Ok.

Thanks for your response guys . I am sorry for the lack of information.Hopefully this information will help you Mr.Charlie .

- Why the technician believes it is the computer?

He said because the  Car Diagnostic Scanner showed this message " Immobiliser system not connected. ( or not working . I forget what he said exactly!) ".

- Has this been regularly serviced?

Yes .

- When was the last service?

One week ago .On 13th of June 2017 I changed the engine oil and filter and the car stopped after one or two days!

- What were the symptoms prior to it not starting?

On 7th of June 2017 the car was switching off suddenly while moving in the road and when I was switching it on It was starting at the same moment [this happened many times in two days ].After that I took it to Garage they told me there was problem with the wires that goes to the back of the engine therefore they fixed the wires and the car was working for one week .Then I changed oil and filter of the Engine and washed the Engine .Finally it stopped after one or two days.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question is too broad and "*answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise*" just because there isn't much detail. Can you add details; like why the technician believes it is the computer? Has this been regularly serviced? When was the last service? What were the symptoms prior to it not starting?

Comment: No spark could mean several things: bad ground (possible), bad timing or ignition position sensor (likely), bad computer (most expensive and not likely).

Comment: Dear @CharlieRB  Kindly find the answers of your questions in up.

Comment: Good job adding details. This helps A LOT. Do you think there is any possibility the water from washing the engine has caused a problem where the wiring had an issue?

Comment: Yes because some of wires too old and not coverd by tape.

Answer (score 1):

> I changed oil and filter of the Engine and washed the Engine

Do you mean you washed inside of the engine bay? You could've potentially cause a water ingress into the connectors, which in turn could prevent the computer from getting all the information it needs to work. If water has gotten into the high voltage areas, it can cause short circuits.

Intermittent problems you have experienced in the past seem to indicate a potential problem with connections. I would personally take a good look at all the connectors in the engine bay and check them for corrosion (if they are corroded - cleaning them should help, but keep in mind to protect them from moisture afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have no spark is the most telling symptom. This is rarely the computer. Instead check the following:

- spark plugs (healthy condition, gapped properly and seated properly)
- spark plug wires (proper resistance, not damaged)
- ignitor module
- check all engine grounds